# Network Error 400 in J2ME http Post

Tags: java-me, http-post

I have the Below Method that sends some data to the server.

```
public String postData(String serverUrl, String dataToSend) {
    MessageLogger.logMsg("\n--xxxx--postData()------START-----url : [" + serverUrl + "]\n-----xxxx--dataToSend :[" + dataToSend + "]");
    String strResponse = ""; //we have not received any response from the Server at this point.
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
    HttpConnection httpConn = null;
    DataInputStream inputStream = null;
    DataOutputStream outStream = null;

    try {
        //convert the dataToSend to byte array.
        byte[] dataToSendBytes = dataToSend.getBytes();

        //open the Connection to the server.
        httpConn = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(serverUrl, Connector.READ_WRITE, true);
        if (httpConn != null) {
            httpConn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST); // method used to send the data.
            httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            httpConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Profile/MIDP-1.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.0");
            //httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US"); //language to use.
            httpConn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Close"); //connection should be closed after request is finished==>solves persistentConnection Error.
            //setting the Content-length could have issues with some Servers===>
            //if the dataToSend is Empty String => contentLen = 0 , else get length of the dataBytes.
            String contentLen = ((dataToSend.length() > 0) ? Integer.toString(dataToSend.getBytes().length) : Integer.toString(0));
            httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-length", contentLen); //not working on Emulator ....enable on shipping application.

            if (!dataToSend.equals("null") || dataToSend.length() > 0) {
                //At times we dont have any data to send to the Server so check the Length of the datatosend before opening the outStream.
                //open the output Stream to send data to the Server.
                outStream = httpConn.openDataOutputStream();
                int len = dataToSendBytes.length;
                for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    outStream.writeByte(dataToSendBytes[i]); //send the data to the Server
                }

                //closeOutStream(outStream);//close outputStream after sending the Data.
            }

            //get response code on Sending Data===> getting response code automatically flushes the output data.
            ntworkResponseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();

            //create a network Timeout Task that checks the connection after 10seconds.
            scheduleNetworkRetry(); ///===>invoke this when catching Errors ===>response ="" throws IOexception.

            if (ntworkResponseCode == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                //connection to server was ok -----read response from server
                stopNetworkTimer(); //Server Connection Ok stop timer to avoid interuption during Reading==>Timer will be started by ReadTimer if Required.
                //show that the connection was successful.
                cmdHandler.updateConnectionMessages(" Server Connection Successful.....\n Fetching Data.....\n");
                MessageLogger.logMsg("NetworkConnector---sendData()---Connection Successful.---response Code [" + ntworkResponseCode + "]");
                if (httpConn != null) {
                    //read the Response From the Server-----------
                    inputStream = new DataInputStream(httpConn.openInputStream()); // open the inputStream.

                    //start the ReadTimer before we start Reading Response From Server
                    readTimer.startReadTimer();

                    int read;
                    while ((read = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
                        sb.append((char) read);

                        readTimer.resetCounter(); //reset the timer on every read of a character==>to be fair to waitTime.
                    }

                    //stop the readTimerThread we have finished...reading
                    readTimer.stopReadTimer();
                    stopNetworkTimer();//stop timer here we are done reading response

                    //store the server response in a String.
                    strResponse = sb.toString();

                    if (strResponse.equals("")) {
                        //failed to Get Response From Server throw an IOException
                        cmdHandler.updateConnectionMessages(" Failed to Get Server Response :[" + strResponse + "] \n");
                        throw new IOException(" Failed to Get Server Response: [" + strResponse + "]");
                    }

                    MessageLogger.logMsg("------sendData()---serverResponse =[" + strResponse + "]");
                }
            } else {
                //connection problem occured.
                MessageLogger.logMsg("NetworkConnector --- sendData() ------Connection Problem  serverResponse Code [" + ntworkResponseCode + "]");
                //connection failed throw connectionException
                throw new IOException("Connection Failed..\n Http Response Code: [" + ntworkResponseCode + "]");
            }

        }// the httpConnection Not null.--end.

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException arge) {
        MessageLogger.logErrorMsg("--------------sendData() --IllegalArgumentException:[" + arge.getMessage() + "]");
        strResponse = CONNECTION_EXCEPTION;
    } catch (ConnectionNotFoundException cone) {
        MessageLogger.logErrorMsg("--------------sendData() ---ConnNotFoundException: [" + cone.getMessage() + "]");
        strResponse = CONNECTION_EXCEPTION;
        retryConnection = true;
        //show the exception generated by the Server.
        cmdHandler.updateConnectionMessages("Connection Not Found :[" + cone.getMessage() + "]\n");
        // retry the connection to the server.
        scheduleNetworkRetry();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        MessageLogger.logErrorMsg("--------------sendData() ----IOException :[ " + ioe.getMessage() + "]");
        strResponse = CONNECTION_EXCEPTION;
        retryConnection = true;
        //show the exception genereated by the server.
        cmdHandler.updateConnectionMessages("Connection Problem\n : [" + ioe.getMessage() + "]\n");
        // retry the connection to the server.
        scheduleNetworkRetry();
    } catch (SecurityException se) {
        //user cancelled the Connection Request.
        MessageLogger.logErrorMsg("--------------sendData() -----SecurityException :[" + se.getMessage() + "]");
        strResponse = CONNECTION_EXCEPTION;
    } finally {
        //close all the connection streams
        try {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                //close the inputStream
                inputStream.close();
                inputStream = null;
            }

            if (outStream != null) {
                //close the outStream.
                outStream.close();
                outStream = null;
            }

            if (httpConn != null) {
                //close  the connection object.
                httpConn.close();
                httpConn = null;
            }

        } catch (IOException ie) {
            MessageLogger.logErrorMsg("Finally----Exception : [" + ie.getMessage() + "]");
        }
        MessageLogger.logMsg("--finally----END--------inside Finally-----httpCon=" + httpConn + "instream = " + inputStream);

    }
    MessageLogger.logMsg("---xxxx---postData()------------END--------responseGot =[ " + strResponse + " ]\n ----maxConnReached=[" + connectionMaxReached + "]-----");
    return strResponse;
}
```

The code works fine. However I have noted a Bug; if the String dataToSend is large then It fails to POST and I get the following error (Http Response Code: [400]) from my  Logger Method

```
--xxxx--sendData()----scheduleNetworkRetry()-----networkCode=[400]--START------
--xxxx----scheduleNetworkRetry()---
xxxxx----scheduleNetworkRetry()------ntworkTask =      app.utilities.NetworkConnector$NetworkTimeoutTask@efb4d042   Timer = java.util.Timer@1fd138a9
 NetworkConnector --- sendData() ------Connection Problem  serverResponse Code [400]
--xxx--updateConnectionMessages()---Msg =Server Connection Failed : [Connection Failed..
Http Response Code: [400]]
```

How would I go about remedying this error. Note This error has been recreated in both Mobile Device and Emulator

Answer (score 0):

The following tells us that the request was sended to the server and the server did not like it:

```
Connection Problem  serverResponse Code [400]
```

(the string "Connection Problem" is from your code, so it is misleading here).

The next thing you need to do is find out what the server did not like.

If you have access to the server, look for the error.log file. There should be a hint what the problem is. 
It may also that some kind of firewall has blocked the request. Sometimes there is a limit of the maximum length of post vars.

If you don't have access to a server, than try to send an identical request with a different technology
(html form, script language of your choice or a simple command line java app) This makes it easier to experiment to find the problem.

Comment: I changed the following  httpConn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST); to  httpConn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET); and was able to remedy the issue on the Emulator. As  it stands now The requests are reaching the server as expected from emulator but not on real phone.  On device I still get the error 400. On inspecting the error_log on the server there is nothing to report about.If I use a different method there is nothing wrong and everything is working